# How to Identify Sheet Music Type, Era, or Origin?

Tags: sheet-music, frequency, rock-n-roll

Asking for some help here…maybe someone will recognize what kind of sheet music this is.

I’m attempting to recreate the framed sheet music hung on the wall in the photos. This is my father sometime in the late 70s or 80s. His big 60th bday is coming up soon and I’d like to recreate that poster he had framed behind him. I think it was something special to him, considering he had it framed, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what kind of sheet music it is, let alone what song it portrays. Any particular instruments or vocals shown here? I notice two treble clefs. Are the colored sections depicting frequencies? How do I interpret these measures, and go about discerning a melody?

Any direction or assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image: dad with sheet music]

[image: sheet music closeup]

Comment: Voted to re-open. This is a how-to question, not an identification question.

Comment: @Aaron I see your point, but doesn't your answer ultimately boil down to "I knew the piece, so I was able to Google it"? In other words, is the "how-to" portion of your answer not just "know the piece"?

Comment: @Richard That's fair, but the question itself does still fit our guidelines. My feeling is that closing it sends a mixed signal, especially to new users, who make an effort to meet site standards. I could get behind a more specific close reason so that there is some guidance for OP and others who come across the question.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind an easy identification question like this, but that is all it is. The only 'how to' about it is how to read music and then recognize the Beethoven motif. BTW, if it wasn't such a super famous motif, the picture is way to out of focus to do a read identification/score reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a portion of Beethoven's Fifth Symphony. The poster is titled "Sony Tape. Full Color Sound" (1979), by Milton Glaser ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_Glaser)).

You can see a complete image at [Milton Glaser Studio](https://www.miltonglaser.com/store/c:posters/840/sony-tape-full-color-sound-1979).

To identify it, I was able to see in the lower of the two systems that all instruments in the first two measures appeared to have the same "fate motif" rhythm as in Beethoven's Fifth. It also appeared that the second measure was a step lower in pitch than the first, again consistent with Beethoven's Fifth.

From there, I did a Google search for "Beethoven's Fifth Colorized poster", and the link the the Milton Glaser store was on the first page of results.

Comment: Mind blown. Seriously. I mean, sure the 5th is very famous, but still. I can't even identify anything remotely resembling a measure in that picture.

Comment: @Creynders If you haven't already, it helps to rotate the picture (or, in my case, the laptop). If you look at the bottom-most staff, you can reasonably make out a grouping of three eighth notes followed by a non eighth-note, then the pattern repeats.

Comment: Yeah ... but no, I really don't! :-)